# Проверка строки на недопустимые символы

Tags: php

Имею список недопустимых символов:
ⒶⒷⒸⒹⒺⒻⒼⒽⒾⒿⓀⓁⓜⓃⓄⓅⓆⓇⓈⓉⓊⓋⓌⓍⓎⓏ 
Имею сообщение
ⒽⒺⓁⓁⓆ
Так вот нужно проверить строку на наличие этих символов.
Спасибо!

Comment: https://unicode-table.com/ru/24CB/ + Как экранировать \u символы вы знаете?

Comment: `perg_match('/[ⒽⒺⓁⓁⓆ]/u', строка)`

Comment: Вы можете использовать даже более сложные regexp благодаря поддержке UTF-8: `if (preg_match('/[Ⓐ-Ⓩ]/i', $string)) <недопустимые символы>`. И второй вариант - сделать список разрешенных символов, а все остальные заменить на ничего

Comment: проблема в том что оно и русские буквы считает "недопустимым" символом

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *проблема в том что оно и русские буквы считает "недопустимым" символом*

Вроде бы корректно всё работает:

```
$str = 'Имею список недопустимых символов: ⒶⒷⒸⒹⒺⒻⒼⒽⒾⒿⓀⓁⓜⓃⓄⓅⓆⓇⓈⓉⓊⓋⓌⓍⓎⓏ Имею сообщение ⒽⒺⓁⓁⓆ Так вот нужно проверить строку на наличие этих символов. Спасибо!';

echo preg_replace('~[Ⓐ-Ⓩ]~iu', '', $str);
```

Результат:

```
Имею список недопустимых символов: Имею сообщение Так вот нужно проверить строку на наличие этих символов. Спасибо!
```